# Word having single quotes search from xml file using jquery issue

Tags: html, xml, jquery-ui, jquery

Hi I need to parse XML file using jquery. I created read and display functionality. But when a word having single quote not working.

My XML is like this

```
<container>
<data name="Google" definition="A search engine"/>
<data name=" Mozilla's " definition="A web browser"/>
</ container>
```

using my jquery code I can read definition of Google. But I can't read Mozilla's definition due to that single quotes. This is my jquery code.

```
    var displayDefinition = function(obj){
        $.get("definitions.xml", function(data){
         xml_data1.find("data[name^='"+obj.innerHTML+"']").each(function(k, v){


     right=''+ $(this).attr("Defination") + '';
         }
        }
    $(".result").append(right);

    }
```

Any body knows the solution for this please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery deals with single quotes very well.  the structure of your function looks really wild though.  I changed it a big assuming you want to create a function that can display the definition based on passing it a name: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/VQxZ2/

```
function display(id) {
    $('container').find('data[name="' +id.trim()+ '"]').each(function() {
        var right = $(this).attr("definition");
        $(".result").html(right);
    });
}
```

Note, you have to make sure your 'name' attribute does not begin or end with spaces; and just trim the string that the user passes in.

Comment: Hay its not working. can u please tell me why you given that id.trim(). From function call I am passing 'this' object. So I need to use this.innerHTML to take value of the li tag.

Comment: the trim is just in case the user types ' google ', instead of 'google'.  Post the code that is used to call 'displayDefinition'

Comment: <li onclick="displayDefinition(this);">'+$(this).attr("name")+'</li>
this is the function call. Google name doesn't make any problem. If the name is Google's like this make problem. I need to search name='Google's'.. In this case it is not working. Any solution?

Comment: Instead of displayDefinition, use the function I posted.  Instead of onclick='displayDefinition(this);', use onclick='display(this.innerHTML);'.  The rest of your code can remain the same

Comment: sorry I need to change style of that li for that purpose I passed this object instead of this.innerHTML. Also in your function you are not parsing XML file.

Comment: Also, wait for more people to chime in.  I get the feeling your issue may deal more with XML/HTML encoding.

Comment: @rkw let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2252/discussion-between-learner-and-rkw)